# Buffer not reloaded after external command?

Tags: buffers, autocmd

My buffer is able to reload every time I pull changes from the remote, with:

```
autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI * if mode() != 'c' | checktime | endif
autocmd FileChangedShellPost *
      \ echohl WarningMsg | echo "File changed on disk. Buffer reloaded." | echohl None
```

I recently added auto-formatting for Bazel BUILD files, by adding this to my `init.vim`:

```
autocmd BufWritePost BUILD !buildifier <afile>
```

It works in that the file is formatted by `buildifier`, but my buffer is not automatically reloaded to reflect the changes.

Typing `:e` does refresh the buffer, but I can't seem to concatenate this `:e` to `!buildifier <afile>`. I tried:

```
autocmd BufWritePost BUILD !buildifier <afile> | :e
```

and

```
autocmd BufWritePost BUILD !buildifier <afile> | e
```

but both cases had `:e` or `e` recognized as an external command.

What's lacking here to make my buffer auto-reload?

Comment: @Heptite `autocmd BufWritePost BUILD \ !buildifier <afile>`? Isn't that `\` just for line continuation?

Comment: Oops, I was wrong about what to do. I'll write an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that vim is running all of "`buildifier <afile> | e`" as one shell command, which means the shell is being told to pipe the output of "`buildifier`" to the "`e`" shell command (which doesn't even exist for me so I get an error from the shell). You need to prevent that by explicitly telling Vim the "boundary" of the shell command:

```
autocmd BufWritePost BUILD execute "!buildifier <afile>" | e
```